# Huge chunk sizes due to dynamic json imports in production build

Tags: javascript, json, vite

I have a vite SPA and use dynamic imports to load my json files. Since I need to load numerous very large json files, the index.js file in my `/dist` becomes too big in my production build.

What is the best way to import these json files dynamically but still keep small chunks? Can I import somehow the json files dynamically as own chunks, similar to images and videos with hashes?

[image: Too large chunks]

Here my vite.config.js

```
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { name } from './package.json'

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/widgets/' + name + '/',
  server: {
    open: true, // Define a BROWSER in your .env-File to specify which browser. Defaults to Chrome. https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-open
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@Assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
      '@Components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@Examples': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/examples'),
      '@Scripts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts'),
      '@Styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles'),
      '@Cms': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles/cms'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true, // needed for css imported in cms template
  },
  define: {
    __DATA_PATH__: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_config_dataPath),
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    legacy({
      polyfills: true,
    }),
    react(),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      minify: true,
      inject: {
        data: {
          title: name,
          id: name,
        },
      },
    }),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
    svgr(),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that lazy loading helps reduce the file size and splits them into multiple different files. to do this, instead of using
`import Component from "./location/component";`, what you should do is:

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from "react"

const Component = lazy(() => import("./location/component")); / loads a component only when used

return <Suspense fallback="loading..."> /* Shows "loading..." while loading component */
<Component/>
</Suspense>
```

Note that you should know what and what not to lazyload in order to optimize your app and chunk properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this configuration：

```
// vite.config.ts
build: {
  chunkSizeWarningLimit: 500, // default 500 KB
},
```

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-chunksizewarninglimit

Comment: Hey WengX, thank you very much for your answer. But of course I don't want to get rid of the warning message, I would like to reduce the chunk size. But any help is highly appreciated!